# Are extension methods a language feature or that of the CLR?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

C# 3 brought us extension methods.

However, other languages such as VB.NET also implement extension methods by way of specifying an attribute declaration on top of a method which has to be declared in a VB.NET module.

Also, you can use extension methods in C++/CLI.

So, I am wondering if extension methods are a language feature or a feature that's built into the CLR?

I am guessing it is a compiler trick since you can even invoke them as plain static methods of the types they are declared within and therefore must be a language specific feature (and must have been implemented by Microsoft in VB.NET, C# and C++ extensions only for the sake of uniformity, but are not necessary for any other language that wants to target the CLR) but I couldn't be sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are a language extension. As you suspected, the compiler is doing all the work and producing IL code that calls the extension method explicitly as a static method. This can be verified by looking at the IL.

```
IL_0000:  newobj     instance void Sandbox.Program/Foo::.ctor()
IL_0005:  stloc.0
IL_0006:  ldloc.0
IL_0007:  call       void Sandbox.Program::Bar(class Sandbox.Program/Foo)
```

Here I defined a class `Foo` and an extension method `Bar()` and then called `foo.Bar()`.

The dump of the `Bar()` function shows it doesn't do anything special, except for the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute`:

```
.method public hidebysig static void Bar(class Sandbox.Program/Foo foo) cil managed
{
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  // Code size       1 (0x1)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  ret
} // end of method Program::Bar
```

Comment: Correct, you can use extension methods on any version of the .NET Framework, even ones "before" extension methods were introduced simply be creating the appropriate attribute in your solution.

Comment: Thank you, @dvnrrs. So, if I generate an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST), say using System.CodeDOM, of a simple static class that has a single static method but without the first parameter prefixed with the `this` keyword, but instead apply a ExtensionAttribute declaration on the static method, and then I compile the AST using the C# compiler, it won't generate an extension method, right?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 I think it would... the `ExtensionAttribute` is the only difference, at the IL level, between a regular static function that takes an argument of type `T` and an extension method on type `T`. I posted the IL dump above of my sample extension method so you can have a look.

Comment: Thanks, @dvnrrs. I could be thinking wrong, but doesn't that then suggest that extension methods are built into the CLR? That was what got me started thinking about all this actually -- I was wondering if I could generate a CodeCompileUnit/AST for a class with an ExtensionAttribute and generate a C# extension method without using the C# syntax. I am going to also try it in the next 24 hours or so.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 I think you should be able to generate extension methods without using C#, yes. That doesn't mean it's built into CLR. CLR doesn't know anything about "extension methods," it just knows there's a method with an attribute on it. The attribute tells the C# compiler to treat that method syntactically as an extension.

Comment: I see. Then, compilers consume the ExtensionAttribute. Thanks.